# SVG textpath: text is not displayed in the browser

Tags: svg

Could someone validate the svg elements that I have created and explain at all why the text is not displayed?

As a backstory I have a script I'm working on to understand d3.js better and the latest issue is creating a hull to surround  groups of nodes, and insert a label on the path that forms the hull to identify it.

The code generates the nodes, and the surrounding hull fine - the hull is an SVG path, so I should be able to add a text element and a textpath that maps to the path.

Doing some hacking around, I can get text to appear sometimes but writing it 'properly' nothing is displayed.  The resulting svg code is:

```
<g id="hull_elements">
<text>
    <textPath stroke="black" xlink:href="#Secure">Secure</textPath>
</text>
<text>
    <textPath stroke="black" xlink:href="#DMZ">DMZ</textPath>
</text>
<path class="boundary" id="Secure" d="M24.994993112707032,141.1110721988244L207.12813092409354,138.58243426955073L238.50323679510393,118.21543431124748L24.97785884420025,103.5985025585574Z" style="fill: #b0c4de; stroke: #b0c4de; stroke-width: 40px; stroke-linejoin: round;"></path>

<path class="boundary" id="DMZ" d="M88.15998924466983,242.42648560274165L208.29914853798698,349.28995851784157L189.37253440909416,316.73364831006586L117.42121587510853,219.36649184836727Z" style="fill: #b0c4de; stroke: #b0c4de; stroke-width: 40px; stroke-linejoin: round;"></path>
</g>
```

I believe this is valid - and I can easily move the text elements above or below the path but the text still doesn't appear.

The fiddle is at http://jsfiddle.net/zuzzy/hWd7K/1/ and the textpath part is around line 382

Can anyone suggest what is wrong with this?  The odd time I actually get something working (for example see jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/zuzzy/cxnT8/ around line 370 where it is implemented wrongly so far as d3 goes but it actually shows text)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've drawn the path on top of the text so it covers it. If you want to see the text either

a) draw it on top of the path

```
function tick() {
  hullvis.selectAll("path")
        .data(groups)
        .attr("d", groupPath)
        .enter().insert("path", "realnode")
        .style("fill", "lightsteelblue")
        .style("stroke", "lightsteelblue")
        .style("stroke-width", 40)
        .style("stroke-linejoin", "round")
        .attr("class", "boundary")
        .attr("id", function (d) {return d.key;});

    //redraw the hull
    hullvis.selectAll("text")
        .data(groups)
        .enter().append("text").append("textPath")
        .attr("stroke","black")
        .attr("xlink:href", function (d) {return "#" + d.key;})
        .text(function (d) { return d.key;} );
```

or

b) make the path hidden by making it as a child of a `<defs>` tag or visibility:hidden if necessary.

Comment: that was exactly the problem.  I actually made the paths sit within one svg:g and the text/textpath sit in another, so I could control the layering later.  Works now...next job, to understand how to keep the text in roughly one position on the shape given the shape continues to change shape...